# mtrace + MALLOC_TRACE - disable buffering

Tags: glibc, mtrace, malloc-history

how can I disable buffering on `mtrace` and output file with name from `MALLOC_TRACE` ??

the mtrace is started as:

```
$ cat libmtrace1.c
#include <mcheck.h>
static __attribute__((constructor)) void mtrace_install(void) {
    atexit(&muntrace);
    mtrace();
}
$gcc libmtrace1.c -fPIC -shared -o libmtrace1.so
$LD_PRELOAD=./libmtrace1.so MALLOC_TRACE=mtrace_log /bin/ls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey. Just write youself an another mtrace-like plugin and install it using `malloc_hook(3)`.